# React Router 4: Route a page to 404 page if it doesn't match with my routing URLs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
<Route path="/home" component={Dashboard}/>
<Route component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```

I'm getting redirected to 404 page when my urls is `http://localhost:8080/home1` but when I gave the wrong url with sub paths ( `http://localhost:8080/home/1`) it fails to render my `NotFound` component and shows a empty screen. Can anyone suggest me what i'm missing?

Comment: That is how it is supposed to match , as home1 does not match with home. But in the second example it matches correctly and then renders as exact isn't specified

Comment: But it suppose to works when it matches only my Router "path"? Second example was not matched with my paths so it should redirects to 404 page..is my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/home" component={Dashboard}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation in your answer.